# Rails & Devise: chat crashes after delete user account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use Devise for my app auth, and then i intergrated a chat (conversations/messages) function into my app. The chat works fine, but as soon as I deleted the user that I chatted with, the chat page crashes because it "Could not find user id = 1" (ActiveRecord error)

my `conversations controller`:

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @users = User.all
        @conversations = Conversation.all
    end

    def create
        if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).present?
            @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).first
        else
            @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
        end
        redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
    end

    private
    def conversation_params
        params.permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
    end
end
```

my `mesages controller`:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    before_action do
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
    end

    def index
        @messages = @conversation.messages
        @message = @conversation.messages.new
    end

    def new
        @message = @conversation.messages.new
    end

    def create
        @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
        if @message.save
            redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
        end
    end

    private
    def message_params
        params.require(:message).permit(:body, :user_id)
    end
end
```

my `conversation model`:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

    has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
    validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :recipient_id

    scope :between, -> (sender_id, recipient_id) do
        where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ?)", sender_id, recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
    end
end
```

my `message model`:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :conversation
    belongs_to :user

    validates_presence_of :body, :conversation_id, :user_id

    def message_time
        created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%y at %l:%M %p")
    end
end
```

I added Devise the standard way based on the doc, then I added the chat.

UPDATE:

The code crashed at this line: (`views/conversations/index.html.erb`)

```
<% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
      <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id || conversation.recipient_id == current_user.id %>
       <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id %>
         <% recipient = User.find(conversation.recipient_id) %>
       <% else %>
         <% recipient = User.find(conversation.sender_id) %>
       <% end %>
       <h3><%= link_to recipient.email, conversation_messages_path(conversation)%></h3>
      <% end %>
     <% end %>
```

Specifically at `<% recipient = User.find(conversation.sender_id) %>`

About how delete user function works, i didn't code that, i just let Devise do its thing

Comment: In which line of code it crashes? How it should work if you delete a user? Should all his messages be deleted too?

Comment: @Vasilisa updated, check the code

Comment: It's not Devise's work - to delete users, it can only authenticate them. I meant - if you delete a user what should become with his messages and conversation? Should they be deleted too? Or should you just display some kind of label 'Sorry, user was deleted, you can't continue conversation`. You need to think about all this constraints and set up all `dependent: :delete / :nullfy` things and all db foreign key constraints too. Now you have the situation when you conversation has a sender_id, but there is no Sender under the ID, and you don't know, how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

1. add to Conversation where you have `belongs_to` optional: true. Because sender/recepient could be deleted
2. handle in view that they are "nil" and show "deleted" lable
3. try to do `recipient = User.find_by(id: conversation.recipient_id) %> or conversation.recipient` (just use associations) ... and check if object is nil or not